# JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

When using IE10 I am getting the error `JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference` when trying to click a hyperlink to a webpage within the same project, the JavaScript should scroll to the corresponding position on the page.

If I use any other browser, other than IE it works from page to page. If however I use the same references within the same page it will scroll up and down in all browsers, but not in IE when leaving the page.

**Link**

```
<li><a href="index.html#home_section">Home</a></li>
```

I am using `jquery.nav.js` version 3.0.0 and the page is breaking at `var offset = $(target).offset().top;`.

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: Does this help? `scrollTo: function(target, callback) {
   var offset = $(target).offset().top;

   $("html, body").animate({
    scrollTop: offset
   }, this.config.scrollSpeed, this.config.easing, callback);
  },`

Comment: The full code is available at `https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav`

Answer (score 2):

There is some issue with Jquery offset().top calculation for any element if the browser is IE.
To fix this issue you can use the native Javascript for calculating the element offset top and left, and use it accordingly. Here-under the Javascript method that returns the object for calculated top and left for any element in document and it will work for all browsers:

```
function findElementTotalOffset(obj) {
    var oleft = otop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            oleft += obj.offsetLeft;
            otop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    }
    return {left : oleft, top : otop};
}
```

**Example: var offset = findTotalOffset($(target)).top;**